# SQL Server Sub queries/Join Count Based on values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

Please help me with this:

I have the following Data in Table:

```
Menu                    dateTime                  CLI

START                   2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
WELCOME                 2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
LANG_SEL                2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
SERVICE_MENU            2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT        2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
BILLING_MENU            2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
STOP                    2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
START                   2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   2000
WELCOME                 2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   2000
LANG_SEL                2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   2000
BILLING_MENU            2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   2000
STOP                    2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   2000
START                   2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   34543
WELCOME                 2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   34543
LANG_SEL                2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   34543
SERVICE_MENU            2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   34543
BillComplaintSelection  2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   34543
VerbalizeBilltkt        2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   34543
STOP                    2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   34543
START                   2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
WELCOME                 2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
LANG_SEL                2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
BILLING_MENU            2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
VerbalizebillDetails    2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
BILLING_MENU            2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
STOP                    2016-02-23 14:08:52.047   4001
```

My Session is starting with the Value **START** and End's with the value **STOP** I want to Count the occurrence of menu name before **STOP** for each day.

like from the above Data I must get the following OUTPUT:

```
Menu                        Count     DateTime

BILLING_MENU                3        2016-02-23 14:08:52.047
VerbalizeBilltkt            1        2016-02-23 14:08:52.047
```

Comment: which one of two output variations is correct?

Comment: you should use a integer value as ID.

Comment: Please read the question again. I changed the question accordingly for better understanding. thank you

Comment: I dont understand how you want to get this output from this data

Comment: I don't see the logic of counting

Comment: So, you mean this is impossible ?

Comment: _"starting with the Value START and End's with the value STOP I want to Count the occurrence of menu name before STOP for each day"_ - why `BILLING_MENU`, why `3`? why `VerbalizeBilltkt`, why `1`?

Comment: There is no notion of order in your table as long as the datetime values are the same for all records.

Comment: If you see the data you will find that **BILLING_MENU**  occur  three time before **STOP** and **VerbalizeBilltkt** only once before **STOP**

Comment: Data Time are dummy date time.

Comment: what about all others? you want to count exact names? and am I correct that start-stop periods have no sense since you want to filter by date?

Comment: Yes I want to filter them by date but only if there is **STOP** in the next row

Comment: OK, now the logic is clear to me. What about sort order since all rows have the same time?

Comment: Dear let me be more specific, this is actually a table attached to the Interactive Call recorder like any help line that ask customers for language selection and other menus or feedback/complaints. So time could be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that `dateTime` field contains discrete datetime values in ascending order, you can use the following query to identify start/end times of each `START` - `STOP` interval:

```
SELECT t1.`dateTime` AS start_time,  
      (SELECT t2.`dateTime`
       FROM mytable AS t2
       WHERE t2.ID = 'STOP' AND t1.CLI = t2.CLI AND 
             t1.`dateTime` < t2.`dateTime`
       ORDER BY t2.`dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1) AS end_time
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE t1.ID = 'START'
```

Using the above you can implement something like the following to count the number of `ID` appearances among all intervals:

```
SELECT ID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN cnt >= 1 THEN 1 END) AS cnt,
       DATE(start_time)
FROM (       
  SELECT x1.ID, COUNT(*) AS cnt, x2.start_time
  FROM mytable AS x1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.`dateTime` AS start_time,  
          (SELECT t2.`dateTime`
           FROM mytable AS t2
           WHERE t2.ID = 'STOP' AND
                 t1.CLI = t2.CLI AND 
                 t1.`dateTime` < t2.`dateTime`
           ORDER BY t2.`dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1) AS end_time
    FROM mytable AS t1
    WHERE t1.ID = 'START'
  ) AS x2 ON x1.`dateTime` BETWEEN x2.start_time AND x2.end_time
  WHERE x1.ID <> 'START' AND x1.ID <> 'STOP' AND x1.ID <> 'WELCOME'
  GROUP BY ID, x2.start_time, x2.end_time) AS t
GROUP BY ID, DATE(start_time)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20779/8)

**Edit:**

If you just want to count records that occur just before each `STOP` record, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT DATE(`dateTime`), ID, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT t1.`dateTime`, 
        (SELECT ID
         FROM mytable AS t2
         WHERE t1.CLI = t2.CLI AND 
               t2.`dateTime` < t1.`dateTime`
         ORDER BY t2.`dateTime` DESC LIMIT 1) AS ID      
  FROM mytable AS t1
  WHERE ID = 'STOP') AS t
  GROUP BY DATE(`dateTime`), ID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20779/8)

Comment: You are a champion Sir, Please help me with exactly those records that appear just before **STOP** ?

Comment: @BilalAhmed What about those records?

Comment: I need to Count them Sir .

Comment: @BilalAhmed Ok, I had not read the question carefully enough, so I answered a different question! Please have a look at the edit I made.

Comment: Sir you are awesome (Y) I wish I could Give you +1. Thanks again

Comment: @BilalAhmed Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Yes This help me a lot. How to mark this as **Answer** ? I am up voting this answer but it says you are not illegible.

Comment: @BilalAhmed Just click on the tick button.

Answer (score -1):

This may answer your question...

`SELECT 
ID,
COUNT(ID) AS TotalCount, -- You cannot use count as a field name
CAST(DateTime AS DATE) AS DateOnly
FROM TableName
WHERE ID <> 'Start' or ID <> 'Stop'
GROUP BY ID, CAST(DateTime AS DATE)`

Comment: I am sorry but this is not dear.